# How to interchange axis while plot?

Tags: plotting, simplifying-expressions

```
    de = 1;
ch = 0;
Cc = 0;
gm = 0.02;
et = 0.1;
k0 = 0.1;
Mm = de + (gm - 2*et)*x1 + 2*gm*Cc;
y0 = x1*(Mm^2 + k0^2 - ch^2)^2/((Mm - ch)^2 + k0^2);       
Plot[{y0}, {x1, 0, 8} , Frame -> True,  
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x14", Bold, 16], Style["y04", Bold, 16]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], Thickness[0.011]}]
```

i want to interchange axis.In which i want to plot 'x1' v/s 'y0'. and limit of 'y0' should be {0,1}. if anyone can do this is most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

de = 1;
ch = 0;
Cc = 0;
gm = 1/50;
et = 1/10;
k0 = 1/10;
Mm = de + (gm - 2*et)*x1 + 2*gm*Cc;

y0 = x1*(Mm^2 + k0^2 - ch^2)^2/((Mm - ch)^2 + k0^2);

ParametricPlot[{y0, x1}, {x1, 0, 8},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, Automatic},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel ->
  (Style[#, Bold, 16] & /@ {"y04", "x14"}),
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use `ListPlot` with the coordinates and the axis labels swapped, like this

```
xmax = x1 /. Last@Solve[y0 == 1, x1];
ListPlot[Table[{y0, x1}, {x1, 0, xmax, 1/25}],
 Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {y, x},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 8}}]
```

[image]